# Script Writes Correctly, The Graph Still Doesn't Show Up

Tags: matlab

I'm working with k-means in MATLAB. And here is my code:

```
k=input('Enter a number: ');
  [g c] = kmeans(cobat,k,'dist','SqEuclidean');
  y = [cobat g]

  [s,h]=silhouette(cobat,g,'SqEuclidean') %Show the silhouette graphic

  %Show the plot3D graphic
  Colors=hsv(k);
  PlotClusters(cobat,g,c,Colors)
```

When I run it, it works, but why `[s,h]=silhouette(cobat,g,'SqEuclidean')` can't be shown?

When I deleted this line:

```
  Colors=hsv(k);
  PlotClusters(cobat,g,c,Colors)
```

...the silhouette graph can be shown.

What should I do so all the graphs can be shown?

Your help means a lot to me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your `PlotClusters` does, but it may be very well writing to the same figure which was generated by `silhouette`, potentially overwriting the old plot.

Try bringing up a new figure with the `figure` command before the call to `PlotClusters`, like so:

```
figure
Colors = hsv(k)
PlotClusters(cobat,g,c,Colors)
```